# I am unable to send email from java

Tags: java, email, gmail

I am using code like
in the below code userid username username and password gives password of mail from where i am going to send mail

```
Properties props = System.getProperties(); 
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); 
props.put("mail.smtp.host", host); 
props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtps");
props.put("mail.smtp.user", userid); 
props.put("mail.smtp.password", password); 
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465"); 
props.put("mail.smtps.auth", "true"); 
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null); 
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session); 
InternetAddress fromAddress = null;
InternetAddress toAddress = null;

try {
fromAddress = new InternetAddress(from);
toAddress = new InternetAddress(to);
} catch (AddressException e) {

e.printStackTrace();
}

message.setFrom(fromAddress);
message.setRecipient(RecipientType.TO, toAddress);
message.setSubject(subject);
message.setText(text); 

//SMTPSSLTransport transport =(SMTPSSLTransport)session.getTransport("smtps");

Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtps"); 
transport.connect(host, userid, password); 
transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients()); 
transport.close();
```

but it is giving me error like

```
 javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
  nested exception is:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1972)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:642)
```

Can any one suggest me whats problem with my code.....
Thank u in advance.....

Comment: Take a look at this article, they use the port 587 instead: http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-sending-e-mail-via-gmail-smtp-server-with-mailsender/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
```

This is the Properties setup I have used to successfully send an email using a gmail account. you can then create a session using:

```
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(emailAddress, password);
                }
              });
```

It's a slightly different approach, but it's worked in code I'm using.